# reportes pdf con python

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

necesito saber como mostrar los registros de una consulta de la base de datos a un documento pdf usando python y reportlab.

la idea es mostrar una tabla en un pdf donde se incluyan los datos que genera  la consulta a la BD

Answer (score -1):

Este es un ejemplo sencillo:

```
import io
from django.http import FileResponse
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

def generate_report(request):
    # create a file-like buffer to receive PDF data.
    buffer = io.BytesIO()

    # create the PDF object, using the buffer as its "file."
    P = canvas.Canvas(buffer)

    # Draw things on the PDF. Here's where the PDF generation happens.
    # See ReportLab documentation for the full list of functionality.
    p.drawString(100, 100, "Hello World!")

    # Close the PDF object cleanly, and we're done.
    p.showPage()
    p.save()

    # FileResponse sets the Content-Disposition header so that browsers
    # present the option to save the file.
    return FileResponse(buffer, as_attachment=True, filename="hello.pdf")
```

para más información mira este tutorial en youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UVXu-N_Zojw

Comment: Bueno, esto funciona y doy un link para mayor explicación, no entiendo la puntuación negativa